# Sql server Update Query in table with duplicate records

Tags: sql-server-2012

I would like to know what happen when I do an update with duplicated rows, for example:

```
Table 1:

Email               StatusID   Status
phil@gmail.com        NULL      
dome@yahoo.es         1         Busy
phil@gmail.com        2         Online
dome@yahoo.es         NULL      

Table 2:

Email            Name             RejectionStatusID  RejectionStatus  
dome@yahoo.es    Dome                     1               
phil@gmail.com   Phil                     2
```

Result?

```
Update Table2
SET RejectionStatusID = StatusID,
RejectionStatus = Status
FROM Table2 Inner Join Table1
ON Table2.Email = Table1.Email
```

I wouldlike to know which of the duplicated and why??? Not really sure!!! Of course I did the query and know what happen but why? Just want an explanation...
Thanks.

EDITED:
This is the example, this is what happen with null values!!!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ee69/1/0

Answer (score 0):

From BoL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523(v=sql.110).aspx

> The results of an UPDATE statement are undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is not deterministic.